# Merge a structure and a single section

Tags: templating, sections

That is written so inefficently:

```
{% set indexNavi = craft.entries.section('pageContent').level(1).all() %}
{% set bookingLink = craft.entries.section('booking').all() %}

<ul class="navList">
  {% for item in indexNavi %}
    <li>
      <a class="btnLink" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for item in bookingLink %}
    <li>
      <a class="btnLink" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there a better way?

I wanted to creat a single variable:

```
{% set merger = craft.entries.section(['pageContent','booking']).level(1).all() %}
```

But this only outputs the `pageContent`. I guess because booking is a single section and therefore has no `level`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this only outputs the `pageContent`. I guess because `booking` is a single section and therefore has no `level`?

In short, yes. It's not super clean but you could fetch everything without worrying about level:

```
{% set merger = craft.entries.section(['pageContent','booking']).all() %}
```

Then check for `level` in your loop ('normal' entries return `null` as a `level`)

```
{% for item in merger %}
    {% if item.level is null or item.level == 1 %}
        {{ item.title }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```